# How do I attach a PaymentMethod to a stripe Customer in DjStripe?

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I have the following Django class:

```
class PurchaseSubscriptionView(APIView):


    def post(self, request, user_id):
        price_name = request.data.get("price_name")
        payment_method = request.data.get("payment_method")
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)

        customer, created = djstripe.models.Customer.get_or_create(subscriber=user)
        payment_method_json = json.dumps(payment_method)
        customer.add_payment_method(payment_method_json)
        price = djstripe.models.Price.objects.get(nickname=price_name)
        customer.subscribe(price=price)
```

Everything works until customer.add_payment_method(payment_method_json)

At which point I get:

```
stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_8KcCUrPg7z8Aok: No such PaymentMethod: '{\"id\": \"pm_1IaFMyJs57u3g5HDGoe83cGx\", \"object\": \"payment_method\", \"billing_details\": {\"address\": {\"city\": null, \"country\": null, \"line1\": null, \"line2\": null, \"postal_code\": null, \"state\": null}, \"email\": null, \"name\": null, \"phone\": null}, \"card\": {\"brand\": \"visa\", \"checks\": {\"address_line1_check\": null, \"address_postal_code_check\": null, \"cvc_check\": null}, \"country\": \"US\", \"exp_month\": 2, \"exp_year\": 2022, \"funding\": \"credit\", \"generated_from\": null, \"last4\": \"4242\", \"networks\": {\"available\": [\"visa\"], \"preferred\": null}, \"three_d_secure_usage\": {\"supported\": true}, \"wallet\": null}, \"created\": 1617002320, \"customer\": null, \"livemode\": false, \"type\": \"card\"}'
```

What exactly is going on? I passed the PaymentMethod from my client after generating it - this should work, correct? Am I missing any steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `customer.add_payment_method` you're supposed to pass in the PaymentMethod ID, it looks like you're trying to dump the whole JSON object in there instead.

You probably want

```
customer.add_payment_method(payment_method_json.id)
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you! I was struggling with that all of yesterday. Should I only be passing ids in for each of the methods for this particular library?

Comment: As a rule of thumb you never need to pass in whole Stripe object JSON blobs when making requests. In most cases you only need the ID of the object and some additional data.